# Where to search for the core file generated by the crash of a linux application?

Tags: linux, directory-structure, core-dump

I am trying to find out the reason of crash for one of my Linux application. But I don't know where core is going.

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
core.%e.%p
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow: Core dumped, but core file is not in the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2065912/4561887)

Comment: A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away, I worked with a *Unix* (not Linux) system that put core dump files into `/tmp` with filenames like `core.12345` (using the PID).  But that was a specialized, one-off product.  It's probably worth a look, but don't expect to find anything there.

Answer (score 55):

Systems using *systemd* are usually configured to dump cores to

```
/var/lib/systemd/coredump/
```

You may use the `coredumpctl` command to list core dumps.
See also [no-more-coredumps-after-migrating-to-systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65110/no-more-coredumps-after-migrating-to-systemd)

Comment: `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` will not contain any core files unless you have installed `systemd-coredump` and then re run the program that crashes.

Answer (score 53):

The core dump is written in the current directory of the process at the time of the crash.

Of course core dumps need to be enabled, by default those are usually disabled. Check the output of `ulimit -c`, if that's 0 then no core file will be written. Run `ulimit -c unlimited` to enable core dumps; this is a per-process setting which is inherited by processes started by that process.

If a core dump should have been generated but you don't know where, then you could start the process again (if it will without crashing immediately), then check its working directory by doing `ls -l /proc/$pid/cwd` where `$pid` is the process ID of the process. That link will point to the current working directory of that process. Chances are the core dump will be there. Otherwise you need to run `find` on the entire system...

Comment: I have checked ulimit -c its unlimited, but still there is nothing in current directory of process.

Comment: It's possible that the application detected a fatal error itself and aborted, i.e. it's not a "real" crash such as a segmentation violation or similar, which *would* generate a core dump. As you give no information about the application it's not possible to know.

Comment: Its definitely a crash coz I knowingly doing a null pointer.