# How can a poor old non-root user get the core dumps systemd ate?

Tags: systemd, non-root-user, core-dump

As we [know](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65110/no-more-coredumps-after-migrating-to-systemd), with `systemd`, core dumps don't just get written to the current directory but to some obscure journal. Now, I'm a poor old non-root user on some machine, and - I want my core dumps! I can't follow the suggestions to edit files in `/etc` or run `systemd` utilities as root. Can I still get my core dump files somehow?

PS - If it matters, I'm on Fedora 22.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use systemd's `coredumpctl` to list and retrieve your core dumps. Use the PID or name of the program to select one to dump (to file `-o ...`) or to run `gdb` on.

```
$ coredumpctl list
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG PRESENT EXE
Mon 2016-04-11 11:18:23 CEST  21538  1000  1000  11 * /usr/bin/sleep
$ coredumpctl info 21538
           PID: 21538 (sleep)
           UID: 1000 (meuh)
           ...
$ coredumpctl -o core dump sleep
$ coredumpctl gdb 21538
```

(Some intermediate versions of systemd use the name `systemd-coredumpctl`).
Your userid must be in group `systemd-journal` to be able to do this without becoming root.

Comment: I take it I need to specify some list index instead of "dump" in your second line?

Comment: Yes, you need to provide a "match", eg the program that core dumped, or its process id etc.