# Where is core dumped file by handling SIGQUIT stored?

Tags: linux, signals, core-dump

From http://qr.ae/TUTxgN

> SIGQUIT is the dump core signal. The terminal sends it to the
>   foreground process when the user presses `ctrl-\`. The default behavior
>   is to terminate the process and dump core, but it can be caught or
>   ignored. The intention is to provide a mechanism for the user to abort
>   the process. You can look at SIGINT as "user-initiated happy
>   termination" and SIGQUIT as "user-initiated unhappy termination."

```
$ sleep 100
^\[1]+  Done                    nohup sleep 100
Quit (core dumped)
```

But I can't find the dump file in the current directory. Where is it? Thanks.

Comment: '/home/t/core': No such file or directory

Comment: Maybe of help: https://sigquit.wordpress.com/tag/core_pattern/

Comment: Many distros are perfectly happy to disable core generation by default.

Comment: @Ignacio but in that case you don’t get the “(core dumped)” message.

Comment: @StephenKitt  `$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` says `|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P`. Does it tell us where to find the file?

Comment: It should be either in `/var/crash`, or (more likely) `/var/lib/systemd/coredump`. It will be named after the program which crashed.

Comment: @StephenKitt Neither has it. Does `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`  suggest the two places?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks. How can I enable it?

Comment: Core dumps *are* enabled (otherwise you wouldn’t get the “(core dumped)” message). The contents of `core_pattern` indicate that core dumps are fed to `apport`; I’ll look into where it stores them (I thought it would be `/var/crash`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general case is covered by [How to view Core file (general)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316348/86440).

This specific case is different. Your `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` value of `|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P` indicates that your system is set up to use [Apport](https://launchpad.net/apport) to handle core dumps, and that has [special handling of `SIGQUIT`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~apport-hackers/apport/trunk/view/3194/data/apport#L474): instead of feeding the core dump into the system’s error reporting tool, it writes it to a file in the current directory, if the `ulimit` settings allow it, and if the binary being dumped is readable and *not* setuid or setgid. Look at the output of `ulimit -c`: if it’s 0, you won’t get a core, otherwise you will, if the size allowed by `ulimit` (which might be “unlimited”) is sufficient to store the core dump. Apport ensures that you don’t get partial core dumps: if the limit isn’t “unlimited”, core dumps larger than the limit are deleted once Apport realises that it’s going over the limit. The core file will be named `core`, possible followed by `.` and the process identifier (if `/proc/sys/kernel/core_uses_pid` is 1).

Comment: Thanks. Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446472/why-does-the-following-way-not-change-core-file-limit-size