# Why does the following way not change core file limit size?

Tags: bash, ulimit, core-dump

To solve the problem in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446428/674, I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483998/156458, but it doesn't set core file limit size?

```
$ sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && exec su t"

$ ulimit -c
0
```

1. Does this way change the core file limit size temporarily just for the current shell, or permanently for all the shells of all the users or the current user?
2. **Update:** The original post https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483998/156458 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238413/674 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169035/674 all recommended using  `sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && exec su $LOGNAME"`. But  both `ulimit -c 1024` and `exec su $LOGNAME"`  only affects the shell created by `sudo`, so what is the purpose of the command? `exec su $LOGNAME"` also doesn't do anything meaningful to make use of the changed limit.

---

**Note:** I am focusing on why the above way doesn't work, although there are other ways to get around the problem:

1. I should put the command which uses the new limit value inside the
   shell executed by sudo

   e.g.

   ```
   $ sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && sleep 100"
   ^\Quit
   $ ls
   core
   ```
2. I could also try to modify `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: sudo resets the core limit, maybe su behaves the same. https://superuser.com/questions/312648/how-can-i-get-a-core-dump-when-running-a-program-with-sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to address the part:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483998/156458, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238413/674 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169035/674 all recommended using `sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && exec su $LOGNAME"`. But both `ulimit -c 1024` and `exec su $LOGNAME"` only affects the shell created by sudo, so what is the purpose of the command? `exec su $LOGNAME"` also doesn't do anything meaningful to make use of the changed limit. I am very confused and wonder if I am missing something.

I did some experiments, and found that after running

```
sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && exec su $LOGNAME"
```

- `ulimit -c 1024` indeed modify the limit values, but only within the shell under `sudo` under the original shell;
- `exec su $LOGNAME"` will give me a shell under `su` under `sudo` under the original shell, and `su $LOGNAME"` resets the limits  to the default values for user `$LOGNAME`.

So the command suggested by the links don't work.

for core file size:

```
$ ulimit -c -H; ulimit -c;                                                                                                                                                        
unlimited
0
$ ulimit -c 1024
$ ulimit -c -H; ulimit -c;                                                                                                                                                        
1024
1024
$ ulimit -c 10000
bash: ulimit: core file size: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
$ sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 10000 && ulimit -c -H && ulimit -c && exec su $LOGNAME"
[sudo] password for t:
10000
10000
$ ulimit -c -H; ulimit -c;                                                                                                                                                        
unlimited
0

$ ~/bin/get-ancestry-processes.sh
systemd,1 splash
  └─lxterminal,1242,t
      └─bash,22778
          └─sudo,22800,root sh -c ulimit -c 10000 && ulimit -c -H && ulimit -c && exec su t
              └─su,22802 t
                  └─bash,22803,t
                      └─get-ancestry-pr,22819 /home/t/bin/get-ancestry-processes.sh
                          └─pstree,22820 -G -a -s -l -p -u 22819
```

for number of opened files, to redo the experiment at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238413/674, but with a different limit value to set to

```
$ ulimit -n -H; ulimit -n;                                                                                                                                                        
1048576
1024
$ ulimit -n 512
$ ulimit -n -H; ulimit -n;                                                                                                                                                        
512
512
$ ulimit -n 10000
bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
$ sudo sh -c "ulimit -n 10000 && ulimit -n -H && ulimit -n && exec su $LOGNAME"
10000
10000
$ ulimit -n -H; ulimit -n                                                                                                                                                         
1048576
1024
```

Answer (score 9):

According to the manpage, `ulimit` "provides control over the resources available to the shell and to processes started by it". So the `ulimit` value is valid for the current shell.

You are invoking `ulimit` in a subshell, and when it terminates you're back to the default `ulimit` value.

```
[root@centos7 ~]# ulimit -c
0
[root@centos7 ~]# ulimit -c 1024
[root@centos7 ~]# ulimit -c
1024
```

Answer (score 4):

The `ulimit` command works for the shell that calls it and for it's descendants.

The command `su` will have the limit you did set up. The parent shell is not affected.

Comment: Thanks. The original post https://stackoverflow.com/a/17483998/156458 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238413/674 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169035/674 all recommended using  `sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && exec su $LOGNAME"`. But  both `ulimit -c 1024` and `exec su $LOGNAME"`  only affects the shell created by `sudo`, so what is the purpose of the command? `exec su $LOGNAME"` also doesn't do anything meaningful to make use of the changed limit. I am very confused and wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: Not all answers on stackexchange are correct. I did add some comments to the names questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

> I am very confused and wonder if I am missing something

I think you are missing (or not recognizing) `/etc/security/limits.conf`
Here is the template from  Suse Linux Enterprise Server 11.4, *and also how I globally set the stacksize limit to unlimited versus the default 8KB.*

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - an user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
#        - the wildcard *, for default entry
#        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax,
#                 for maxlogin limit
#
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit (KB)
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to values: [-20, 19]
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
#
*       hard    stack   unlimited
*       soft    stack   unlimited
*       hard    nofile  100000
*       soft    nofile  100000
```

This is from SLES, the `limits.conf` name and location might be different depending on your distribution of linux.  Setting the values here will be global and be in effect for everything/everyone rather than using `ulimit`  which would be limited to the scope of the shell window as was described.

**Be forwarned, setting some items improperly can prevent you from logging into your system**

Comment: Thanks. I am confused with `sudo sh -c "ulimit -c 1024 && exec su $LOGNAME"`. The links suggesting this command are all highly upvoted. I can't understand how the command can solve any problem.

Comment: so i did not bother reading any of your links or the background to using `ulimit` within a shell; I never use `ulimit` unless it is something quite specific and for troubleshooting like how i found a piece of software increased to thousands of open file pointers when scaling analysis up to bigger model more cpu cores so i had to increase `nofile`.

Comment: the ulimit is limited in scope to the one shell it's used in, very useful for knowledgeable users who need the power to make that kind of change and it's **safe** because it is limited to that one shell, not their entire login session nor anyone else.  I believe it is also limited by the *hard* and *soft* settings/defaults in `limits.conf` but don't quote me on that... my hard disk is 300gb and my RAM is 512gb I (or someone) could easily crash my server filling up disk with core size set to unlimited running/debugging a simple c code.

Answer (score 0):

Your own answer now contains the information that would have been needed in the question already:

Your system has an unusual setup.

On Solaris, you have the following limits and the POSIX set of resources:

```
LC_ALL=C ulimit -aHS
-t: time(seconds) unlimited:unlimited
-f: file(blocks) unlimited:unlimited
-d: data(kbytes) unlimited:unlimited
-s: stack(kbytes) 10240:unlimited
-c: coredump(blocks) unlimited:unlimited
-n: nofiles(descriptors) 256:65536
-v: memory(kbytes) unlimited:unlimited
```

On Linux you have the following typical limits:

```
ulimit -aSH
-t: time(seconds) unlimited:unlimited
-f: file(blocks) unlimited:unlimited
-d: data(kbytes) unlimited:unlimited
-s: stack(kbytes) 8192:unlimited
-c: coredump(blocks) 0:unlimited
-m: memoryuse(kbytes) unlimited:unlimited
-u: processes(count) 26633:26633
-n: nofiles(descriptors) 1024:1048576
-l: memlock(kbytes) 64:64
-M: addressspace(kbytes) unlimited:unlimited
-L: locks(count) unlimited:unlimited
-i: sigpending(count) 26633:26633
-q: messagequeues(count) 819200:819200
-e: schedpriority(nice) 0:0
-r: rtpriority(nice) 0:0
-R: rttime(usec) unlimited:unlimited
```

As you see, the hard limit is much bigger than yours. This is the reason why nobody could understand your problems.

Since an ordinary user is allowed to raise the soft limits to the hard limits, the request in your question would not need root privileges.