# Can `su` preserve resource limits?

Tags: su, shadow-utils

I am under user `t` and then switch to `t` again via `su t`:

```
$ ulimit -c -H; ulimit -c
1000
1000
$ su t
Password: 
$ ulimit -c -H; ulimit -c
unlimited
0
```

Is it possible to request `su` to preserve resource limit, just like `sudo` which can:

```
$ ulimit -c -H; ulimit -c
1000
1000

$ sudo bash -c "ulimit -c -H; ulimit -c"
1000
1000
```

Thanks.

Here I am trying to find a solution to make https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446811/674 work.

Comment: I think it won't work. It only applies to subshells.