# Is this segment fault raised when running `shuf`?

Tags: bash, scripting, segmentation-fault, shuf

I have a script, where there is a line:

```
eval for i in \{"$1".."$2"\}\; do [ ! -e "$3"/\$i.\* ] \&\& echo \"\$i\" \;  done \| shuf \| mycommand "$3"
```

which means: first create a sequence of numbers where no files named after the numbers exist, pipe them to `shuf`, and then pipe them to `mycommand` which is an ELF executable.

Most of time the script runs fine, but sometimes it gets segment fault error, i.e. The segment fault error is not reproducible.

```
$ myscript 0001 734  XMJ

/home/tim/bin/myscript: line 25: 10170 Exit 1                  for i in {0001..734};
do
    [ ! -e XMJ/$i.* ] && echo "$i";
done
     10171 Done                    | shuf
     10172 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) | mycommand XMJ
```

Does that mean that the segment fault is raised when running `shuf`?

What can we deduce from the error message and possibly correct it?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a horrible use of `eval`. Try `for i in $(seq "$1" "$2"); do...` and trade an external process for readability.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "trade an external process "? Can you be more specific of how to write the script without eval?

Comment: you need `seq -w` for those leading zeroes (and seq would be the external process, vs. {x..y} being done by bash itself)

Comment: Some people to prefer to use shell builtin commands where possible instead of taking the performance hit of spawning an external command.

Comment: @Tim: you can probably identify the core dump like so https://stackoverflow.com/a/13308949/2876682 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48956950/2876682

Comment: @frostschutz I don't know where  the core dump file was created?  I remember by default of ulimit, no dump created. The segment fault error is not reproducible.

Comment: @glennjackman then `i="$1"; while [[ $i -le "$2" ]]... ((i++))` and still avoid that horrible `eval`.

Comment: If the message says “(core dumped)” then core really was dumped.

Comment: @StephenKitt what decides whether a process can create a core stump?   Where can I look up the dump file?

Comment: @Tim see [How to view Core file (general)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316348/86440).