# What decides where core dump files are created?

Tags: ubuntu, core-dump

Does `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` decide where core dump files are created? Mine looks like

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P
```

which I guess means to pipe the core dump to the `apport` script. Will the `apport` script write the input core dump to some file? If yes, where will the file be created? (My `/var/crash/` doesn't have a core dump file from the following commands, and `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` is always empty for the following commands.)

When the soft limit for core file is 0, there is no core dump file in the current directory. Where is it created? ("[If the message says “(core dumped)” then core really was dumped.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478535/is-this-segment-fault-raised-when-running-shuf#comment874875_478535)")

```
$ ulimit -S -c 
0
$ sleep 10
^\bash: line 1: 11837 Quit                    (core dumped) sleep 10
$ ls core
ls: cannot access 'core': No such file or directory
```

When I increase the soft limit, why do I get a core dump file in the current working directory?

```
$ ulimit -S -c 1024;
$ ulimit -S -c;
1024
$ sleep 10
^\Quit (core dumped)
$ ls core
core
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the last part (a `core` file is created in the current directory if `ulimit -c unlimited` was set) also happen if you set (as root) `systctl kernel.core_pattern='|/bin/true'`? (this should cause a process killed with `SIGQUIT` to report `(core dumped)`, but no core file to be written anywhere).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18368068/10306503, especially the part about how `apport` is doing itself the core file creation in cwd